# Alter nested observable values

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

```
return this.http.get(environment.remoteUrl + '/client').pipe(pluck('rows'), map((i: any) => i.doc));
```

I get data in the following structure:

```
{ 
   rows: [
       {x: 123, doc: {a: 2}}, 
       {x:222, doc: {a: 1}}
   ], 
   c: 'hello', 
   b: 3 
}
```

I will only return the both docs under rows to the subscriber.

But it seems the map function did not work as i expect, because undefined is returned.

I expect `[ {a: 2}, {a: 1} ]`

I found a solution:

```
.pipe(pluck('rows'), flatMap((i: any) => i), map((i: any) => i.doc), toArray());
```

But hope there is a shorter way!?

Comment: what output you are expecting?

Comment: @PareshLomate I have updated first post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pluck('rows'),
```

That transforms each emitted event into its rows property. So it emits

```
[
   {x: 123, doc: {a: 2}}, 
   {x:222, doc: {a: 1}}
]
```

You now want to transform this array into another array, containing only

```
[ {a: 2}, {a: 1} ]
```

So you need a `map` operator, and this map operator must transform an array into another array. That can be done using `Array.map()`:

```
map(arrayOfXAndDocs => arrayOfXAndDocs.map(xAndDoc => xAndDoc.doc))
```

Defining types for your structures and using them instead of using `any`, and using understandable names rather than `i`, helps a lot.

Note that the pluck followed by the map can be reduced into a single operation:

```
map(objectWithRows => objectWithRows.rows.map(xAndDoc => xAndDoc.doc))
```

This avoids the ugly `pluck()` operator, which isn't type-safe.